# Search with Ajax

Tags: ajax, jsp

I have a **search.jsp** page that waits for parameters to be sent to it so it could query the database. I intend to use ajax to pass the search parameter to the **search.jsp** page.

```
Job No: <input type="text" name="job"/>
        <a href="search.jsp?job=<%=job%>" class="search">Search </a>
```

How do I get the information the user enters in the **Job No** field put it in <%=job%>  and submit it without page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.org)

```
$(".search").keyup(function(){   
     $("#search_results").load('search.jsp?job='+$("input[name='job']").val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is an autosuggest feature and there are quite a few (good) javascript plug-ins available for that. You might want to think integrating one of those to your implementation rather than re-inventing the wheel. Here is one jquery plug-in that I have used in the past. It is very easy to integrate and does a good job: http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin